# How to sudo as a different user inside a script?

Tags: unix, switch-statement, sudo

I have a wrapper script which calls two scripts aaa.sh and bbb.sh. These two scripts should be executed as different users as

sudo -H -u user1

. /user/bin/scripts/aaa.sh

sudo -H -u user1

. /user/bin/scripts/bbb.sh

but the sudo command can't be executed inside a script. Need help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to switch users, you should use 'su' not sudo, right?

```
su user1 -c ./user/bin/scripts/aaa.sh
```

(that is unless you actually do need elevated privileges)

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` can be used inside a script, but is the user that executes this script actually allowed to use `sudo`? Check your `/etc/sudoers` file.

Answer (score 0):

sudo can be used only if the user name is mapped in /etc/sudoers file as mentioned above. But he may not have the complete priveleges as compared to su user.